# Examples of leaflet interactive mapping applications

Tags: leaflet

I would like to develop a simple mapping application. One where users can digitize lines, polygons and points and attribute the features. The attributes will then be stored in a database for later assessment.

Has anyone seen such an app using the leaflet library?

Comment: +1. Would also love to learn leaflet without having to go the OpenLayers route first.

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet.draw is a plugin which adds the ability to draw in Leaflet.
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw

Check out the [demo](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/) to see how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I made an example using CouchDB as the back end. Won't easily transfer to another DB though.
http://calvin.iriscouch.com/leafletcouch/_design/leaflet/index.html